# Xcode 4 'invalid signature' error

Tags: xcode4, signature, mac-app-store

I have developed a mac app, and am trying to upload it to the mac app store, but am running into difficulties.  Every time i try and submit or validate in Organiser, it comes up with the following error:

"The product archive package's signature is invalid. Ensure that it is signed with your "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificate."

I have signed it with my installer certificate, and the application certificate, have downloaded the Worldwide Developer Relations certificate, but it still refuses to work.  I have tried many of the solutions on the internet, but with no joy.

Comment: The code signing and provisioning process is a bit convoluted IMO; if you don't understand each step in detail then sometimes it's worth starting from scratch.  Revoking and deleting all your certificates and profiles, and starting again.  This can actually help you learn the process again, to aid future problem solving in this area.

Comment: Okay, i have tried that, i have tried copying all my code over to a new project, deleting all the certificates and profiles, revoking them on iTunes connect, but it still comes up with the same error, which is most infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to try signing your app from command line, using the `/Developer/usr/bin/codesign` tool:

```
codesign -s "name of your signing cert" /path/to/MyApp.app
```

`codesign` has a number of options and a man page. It may help spotting the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: This does't work either i'm afraid, I have no idea what the problem is still